# what we mean by JAXB default behaviors?

Tags: jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I am very new to JAXB, and I am confused about the JAXB default behaviors, what I understand is:

JAXB tries to create a JAXBContext if possible by autodetectinh the involved classes. For example, JAXB can read XML documents that don't exactly match what's expected. This is the default behavior of the JAXB unmarshaller.
For example if we have a Foo class:

```
@XmlRootElement
class Foo{
  @XmlAttribute
  String name;
  @XmlElement
  String title;
}
```

The Foo class is a representative Java class for the following document:

```
<foo name=” element-value”>
    <title>some title</title>
</foo>
```

Then if we have an XML instance for the following document where the content of  element is represented by the Foo class.

```
<anotherTagName  name=”element-value”>
    <title>some title</title>
</anotherTagName>
```

We can unmarshal this into a Foo class, use the version of the unmarshal method that takes the 'expectedType' argument, as follows:

```
JAXBElement<Foo> root = um.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new File(“output.xml”)),   
                                     Foo.class);
 Foo foo = root.getVlaue();
```

is that a default behavior of JAXB or not? do I get the point or I'm lost?

Answer (score 0):

> is that a default behavior of JAXB or not?

Yes that is expected JAXB behaviour.  If you specify the class that you wish to unmarshal, you will receive an instance of that type wrapped in an instance of `JAXBElement` that holds onto the root element information.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-no-annotations-required.html